# Javascript/nodejs Azure Service Bus Complete a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I have an application in nodejs using library @azure/service-bus. I am receiving messages using following code:

```
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");

const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

// createReceiver() can also be used to create a receiver for a subscription.
const receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(queueName);
const myMessages =   await receiver.receiveMessages(1);
```

BUT after receiving the message , it is still there in service bus. Accordig to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/service-bus-readme?view=azure-node-latest, I need to use completeMessage function to get it out of service bus, but how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try calling [`completeMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusreceiver?view=azure-node-latest#completeMessage_ServiceBusReceivedMessage_) using something like:

```
await receiver.completeMessage(myMessages[0]);
```

Comment: You are such a life saver. Thank you